# Как создать звуки на питон?

Tags: python, аудио, поиск-библиотек

Как создать звук и воспроизвести его, и возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: Начинающим программистам лучше учиться азам. Изучать сложные библиотеки (а простыми они редко бывают) лучше уже когда свободно читаешь питон. Но в любом случае вопрос нужно конкретизировать. Откуда вы хотите брать звук? Как вы хотите его воспроизводить? Нужно больше деталей.

Comment: Спасибо, питон я уже читать умею) Я хотел создать звук (ну например у меня есть робот на питоне и там такая программа для создания звука: hub.start.beep(60, 10) - начать звук с чистотой 60, 10) и я хотел сделать что-то похожее например: a = beep(60, 10) start.sound(a) Так можно сделать или нет?

Comment: Вот тут предлагается несколько вариантов, в том числе посмотрите Pyo из комментариев к вопросу: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770073/sound-generation-synthesis-with-python

Comment: А за что минусы?(

Comment: Подозреваю потому что слишком расплывчатый вопрос, без конкретики. Тут и DSP и TTS, denoise и еще много чего можно накидать. И всё будет создание звука.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть небольшой пример, но это больше баловство:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

# Задаем параметры для звука
sample_rate = 44100  # частота дискретизации (количество сэмплов в секунду)
note_duration = 0.1  # длительность звука каждой ноты (в секундах)
fade_duration = 0.1  # длительность затухания (fade-out) в конце каждой ноты (в секундах)

# Функция для создания массива 1-битных сэмплов с плавным затуханием
def generate_smooth_1bit_samples(freq):
    t = np.linspace(0, note_duration, int(note_duration * sample_rate), False)
    fade_out = np.exp(-(t - (note_duration - fade_duration)) / fade_duration)
    samples = 32767.0 * np.where(t % (1 / freq * 2) < (1 / freq), 1, -1) * fade_out
    return np.array(samples, dtype=np.int16)
    
    
melody = [220.00, 293.66, 329.63, 392.00, 440.00, 493.88]

# Создаем массив сэмплов для мелодии с плавным затуханием
all_samples = np.concatenate([generate_smooth_1bit_samples(freq) for freq in melody])

# Воспроизводим мелодию из массива сэмплов
sd.play(all_samples, samplerate=sample_rate)
sd.wait()  # Ожидание завершения воспроизведения
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import winsound

#winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)

#Звуковой сигнал частотой 10кГц, длительность 5 сек
winsound.Beep(10000, 5000)
```

Слушаю в наушниках.

Comment: Работать будет, естественно, только на Windows

Comment: в наушниках круто (минус уши))